# carmen rails undefined method `country_code' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined, carmen

I'm having the following error while trying to pass locals to the partial:

> undefined method `country_code' for nil:NilClass

This is what my code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Trial</title>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('select#order_country_code').change(function(){select_wrapper = $('#order_state_code_wrapper');
$('select', select_wrapper).attr('disabled', true);
country_code = $(this).val();
url = "subregion_options?parent_region=#{country_code}";
$('#order_state_code_wrapper').load(url);


});


});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<%= form_for(:order) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :country_code %><br />
<%= f.country_select :country_code, priority: %w(US CA), prompt: 'Please select a country'     %>
<%= f.label :state_code %><br />
<%= render partial: 'subregion_select', locals: {parent_region: f.object.country_code} %>
</div>
<% end %>

</body>
</html>
```

Partial:

```
<div id="order_state_code_wrapper">
<% parent_region ||= params[:parent_region] %>
<% country = Carmen::Country.coded(parent_region) %>

<% if country.nil? %>
<em>Please select a country above</em>
<% elsif country.subregions? %>
<%= subregion_select(:order, :state_code, parent_region) %>
<% else %>
<%= text_field(:order, :state_code) %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

layout false

def index

end

def subregion_options
render partial: 'subregion_select'
end

end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

# The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
# See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"

root 'access#index'

match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
get 'subregion_options' => 'orders#subregion_options'

end
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add this in appropriate action in your controller :

```
@order = Order.new
```

and in view, instead

```
form_for(:order)
```

put

```
form_for(@order)
```

Add to your config/routes.rb following:

```
resources :orders, only: [:index]
```

Answer (score 0):

finally it works after your advice.I also had this wrong and it was not passing parameters in the url :

```
url = "subregion_options?parent_region=#{country_code}";
```

I dont know in cofeescript but in javascript the correct way is like this :

```
url = "subregion_options?parent_region="+country_code;
```